# Minecraft keeps crashing when i click play

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Here's the crash report

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I bet Cylons wouldn't have this problem.

Time: 8/6/16 3:10 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not create context
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(WindowsContextImplementation.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(WindowsContextImplementation.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 58188712 bytes (55 MB) / 154017792 bytes (146 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: After a quick Google search: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?topic=23812.0

Answer (score 1):

It appears that OpenGL, the rendering system Minecraft uses to draw graphics, is not functioning properly. This is noted in the last line, where OpenGL status is listed as "~~ERROR~~" and there is "no OpenGL context found," as well as in the stacktrace, where errors appear to be coming from the OpenGL system. If you have simply gotten Minecraft without editing the file locations, adding mods (which it appears you have not) or editing the resources folder, I do not know why the problem is occurring. However, my best guess is that this is a copy of Minecraft which has been slightly modified, perhaps by moving its file location from where it was originally installed, and some OpenGL file has been skipped in the copying. If you kept the original files, try re-copying the files to a new, empty folder. Otherwise, I don't know what is happening with OpenGL. If the problem persists, my best advice, honestly, is to restart your computer.